# Check if a string surrounded by the special characters is present in another string

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col_1':['filmeinlage federspeicher anlegen',
                 'filmeinlage lm a-kreis', 
                 'weco-pvb-primerspray ral 3012', 
                 'tragrolle unten (metall) talent,t3', 
                 'metallschutzschlauch, spr-va 36', 
                 'gummi pflege liqui moly 500ml', 
                 'gummikugel für 5-stellungskippschalter', 
                 'megaphone er-520 6/10w abs', 
                 'weco primerspray -lar- 3012'],
        'col_2':['lm',
                 'lm', 
                 'pvb', 
                 'metall', 
                 'metall', 
                 'gummi', 
                 'gummi', 
                 'abs', 
                 'lar']
    })
```

I would like to check if the string in Col_2 is present in Col_1, but only if it is on its own or is **surrounded by the special characters**, and if this is the case I would like to return True in the new column and False if otherwise, like shown in the example.  
For an instance if Col_2 has a string '**lm**' and Col_1 has 'fi**lm**einlage' it should return False, but if Col_1 has 'filmeinlage **lm** a-kreis' it should return True

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Desired_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| filmeinlage federspeicher anlegen | lm | False |
| filmeinlage lm a-kreis | lm | True |
| weco-pvb-primerspray ral 3012 | pvb | True |
| tragrolle unten (metall) talent,t3 | metall | True |
| metallschutzschlauch, spr-va 36 | metall | False |
| gummi pflege liqui moly 500ml | gummi | True |
| gummikugel für 5-stellungskippschalter | gummi | False |
| megaphone er-520 6/10w abs | abs | True |
| weco primerspray -lar- 3012 | lar | True |

Comment: Use the `\b` word bounary operator in a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "word boundaries", i.e. "\b" in regexes:

```py
df["new"] = [re.search(fr"\b{re.escape(c2)}\b", c1) is not None
             for c1, c2 in zip(df["col_1"], df["col_2"])]
```

- zip the 2 columns col_1, col_2
- for each pairs, look for a \b-surrounded c2 value in c1

  - c1 and c2 take row values in respective columns in each turn
  - \b means there's not a *word* character there; it might be empty (beginning or end) or parantheses, or space etc.
- if the search does not return None, it means it matches; otherwise, no match
- `re.escape` is there to prevent possible special characters within col_2 values

  - e.g., if a value has "(" in it, it's special to regexes, so it's replaced with "\(" to literally mean parantheses.

to get

```py
>>> df

                                    col_1   col_2    new
0       filmeinlage federspeicher anlegen      lm  False
1                  filmeinlage lm a-kreis      lm   True
2           weco-pvb-primerspray ral 3012     pvb   True
3      tragrolle unten (metall) talent,t3  metall   True
4         metallschutzschlauch, spr-va 36  metall  False
5           gummi pflege liqui moly 500ml   gummi   True
6  gummikugel für 5-stellungskippschalter   gummi  False
7              megaphone er-520 6/10w abs     abs   True
8             weco primerspray -lar- 3012     lar   True
```